# How to manually close the circuit only in hystrix

Tags: hystrix

I want to use Hystrix to automatically falling back to a secondary implementation if the primary command failes. This works kinda well.

But once the primary command failes, and the secondary command is used to process the request, I don't want to switch back to the primary command automatically.

I want a manual "switch back" to the primary command (because there are business needs to do so).

I tried to implement a `HystrixCommandExecutionHook` which works with a state engine which can only be reset external. Once the PrimaryCommand is failed, the StateEngine switches to "circuit open". Whenever the Primary Command is tried to be executed again, the State-Engine is checked in the `onExecutionStart` hook and might raise a custom `RuntimeException`.

This works, but the problem is that once the customer decides to switch back to the primary command, there is no guarantee that the next execution tries to switch back to the primary command so some commands could still be executed as a secondary command by Hystrix.

**tl;dr**

Is there no possibility to just manually close the circuit once it is open without any automatic "magic" on how it is closed again?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is Yes.

You can force close the circuit with the circuit breaker property [`circuitBreaker.forceClosed`](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Configuration#circuitbreakerforceclosed). This property forces the circuit breaker into a closed state when it was set to `true`.